# Char sequence from string at compile time WITHOUT recursion

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, compile-time

Yes, this topic may look as asked already a hundred times, but what I am asking is very different.

Please, don't let me be misunderstood: template recursion can be great and the only way for some idioms when used in C++03, but the problem may arise when using in MSVS 2017/2019 compiler and getting the dreadful  `fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex`.

I know that gcc and clang manage much better recursion than MSVS, but this time the compiler is a contractual subject and can not be changed.

I began using `boost::hana::string`, but with complex strings (over 2000 characters) that error arises.

I wonder if there is some way to replicate the behaviour of `BOOST_HANA_STRING` macro (basically it takes a string and converts it into a char sequence, or wchar depending of input string) but getting rid of recursion.

I guess that the price to pay is to use C++17 exclusively, by using fold instead, but for me this is affordable.

By the way, please do not provide `operator""_cs` solutions, due that MSVS is neither compatible with such gcc extension.

Pseudocode of what I want to achieve:

`STRING("Hello")`   =>   `my_static_string<char, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'>`

Comment: "*over 2000 characters*" Do most compilers allow 2000 elements in a parameter pack? It seems that the problem isn't recursion; it's that the compiler simply doesn't support a pack that big.

Comment: Test the parameter pack; if that is not your problem, then a log depth recursion is possible (in pseudo code, `split(n, seq):={split(n/2,seq).left+split(n-n/2, split(n/2,seq).right).left, split(n-n/2,split(n/2,seq).right).right)` with subexpression saving is log 2 depth in n.  Which means you can make a binary tree and traverse it with only log depth.  But I'd guess hana already does this.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Thank you for your comment, but I disagree with your assertion, at least partially. The same string, with the same length, works fine in Clang and Gcc, but fails in MSVS2017, so the problem is mostly in MS compiler, at least with around 2000 thousand chars. By the way, it is not so much as it looks, markup languages as html or xaml can easily reach that lengths.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont Thank you for your comment. Hana is based in a N-1 recursive pattern and the initial use of std::integer_sequence. Gcc and Clang manage the same string without problem, so I guess MSVS2017 has some problem with recursion (or parameter pack number of elements). But still my question is pending, is it possible get a char sequence from a string without recursion?

Comment: @pablo Make a raw pack with that many elements.  `<'a','a','a',` etc.  Don't disagree, *check*.  The limit will differ by compiler.

Comment: @Pablo: "*so the problem is mostly in MS compiler, at least with around 2000 thousand chars.*" My point is that the limit is *not* "recursion"; the limit is the number of variadic template parameters allowed in a pack. Equally importantly, that limit probably isn't going anywhere, so if you want to run on that compiler, you need to stop trying to process HTML or XAML or whatever at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is some way to replicate the behaviour of `BOOST_HANA_STRING` macro (basically it takes a string and converts it into a char sequence, or wchar depending of input string) but getting rid of recursion.

Well, that's going to be difficult as [`BOOST_HANA_STRING` *doesn't use recursion*](https://github.com/boostorg/hana/blob/master/include/boost/hana/string.hpp#L89):

```
    namespace string_detail {
        template <typename S, std::size_t ...N>
        constexpr string<S::get()[N]...>
        prepare_impl(S, std::index_sequence<N...>)
        { return {}; }

        template <typename S>
        constexpr decltype(auto) prepare(S s) {
            return prepare_impl(s,
                std::make_index_sequence<sizeof(S::get()) - 1>{});
        }
    }

#define BOOST_HANA_STRING(s)                                                \
    (::boost::hana::string_detail::prepare([]{                              \
        struct tmp {                                                        \
            static constexpr decltype(auto) get() { return s; }             \
        };                                                                  \
        return tmp{};                                                       \
    }()))                                                                   \
```

Note the lack of recursion. It's just getting the size of the string, using that to build an index sequence, and using that sequence to build a pack expansion over the elements of the string. It's always exactly 2 function calls deep; no more, no less.

Your problem is not recursion; your problem is that Visual Studio does not support "2000" element parameter packs. The C++ standard only recommends that a compiler support 1024 template arguments, and [Visual C++ support 2046](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-limits?view=msvc-160). I would not bank on this number getting bigger in the future, so you need to find alternate ways of doing whatever it is you're doing here.

Besides, C++20 allows you to create a real compile-time string class that stores an actual array of actual characters that you can actually use in normal, actual code rather than metaprogramming. And they can be used as template parameters; a *single* template parameter. And VC++ already has support for this.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see you were right from the beginning. I was blinded and obfuscated that it was a recursion issue due to unclirified MSVS error message. Sadly, compiler is a contractual matter for me, so I can not use C++20 right now, so I guess I should use runtime strings even if they could be concatenated at compile time...

Comment: Without intrinsic, `std::make_index_sequence` is recursive though.

Comment: @Jarod42 Besides limit of parameter pack, that's a good point